# To reverse a dictionary and display values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to reverse a dictionary and display it in a specific format. Here is the sample input:

```
{'john':34.480, 'eva':88.5, 'alex':90.55, 'tim': 65.900}
```

Output should be:

[image]

This is where I am with the code, but the problem is that it returns a list and not a dictionary.

CODE:

```
def formatted_print(my_dict):
    d = my_dict
    c = sorted(d.items(), cmp=lambda a,b: cmp(a[1], b[1]), reverse=True)
    return (c)
```

Comment: You can't sort a dictionary.  If you want to print it sorted, you need to keep it as a list.

Comment: What do you mean, reverse? How is your result dictionary supposed to look like for the given example? Are you aware of the fact that the order of dictionaries is arbitrary?

Comment: Could it be that you want to sort by value?

Comment: @timgeb I want to sort it by values in descending order.

Comment: dictionaries are not ordered except you use an `OrderedDict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code without importing any module or library :

```
def formatted_print(D):
    list_tuples=sorted(D.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))

    for items in list_tuples:
        x="{0:10s}{1:6.2f}".format(items[0],items[1])
        print(x)
```

It prints:

```
alex       90.55
eva        88.50
tim        65.90
john       34.48
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print your items in a such order you don't need another dictionary, you can just loop over the sorted items and print the keys and values:

```
>>> d = {'john':34.480, 'eva':88.5, 'alex':90.55, 'tim': 65.900}
>>> for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
...     print k, '\t', v
... 
alex    90.55
eva     88.5
tim     65.9
john    34.48
>>>
```

But if you want to preserve the items in a descending order, since dictionaries are not ordered data structures like lists you can use `collections.OrderedDict` in order to create an ordered dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
>>> D = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
>>> 
>>> D
OrderedDict([('alex', 90.55), ('eva', 88.5), ('tim', 65.9), ('john', 34.48)])
```

Comment: It gives an error
NameError: global name 'itemgetter' is not defined

Comment: @Heisenberg Do you import it? `from operator import itemgetter`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to sort it by values in descending order

The standard dictionary has arbitrary order. The only way to sort your dictionary is to sort the (key, value) pairs and build an `OrderedDict` from those:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = {'john':34.480, 'eva':88.5, 'alex':90.55, 'tim': 65.900} 
>>> od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))
>>> od
OrderedDict([('alex', 90.55), ('eva', 88.5), ('tim', 65.9), ('john', 34.48)])
>>> od['eva']
88.5
```

Printing:

```
>>> for name, value in od.items():
...     print name, value
... 
alex 90.55
eva 88.5
tim 65.9
john 34.48
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator

x = {'john': 34.480, 'eva': 88.5, 'alex': 90.55, 'tim': 65.900}
res = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print res

>>> [('alex', 90.55), ('eva', 88.5), ('tim', 65.9), ('john', 34.48)]
```

That's what you are looking for.
You could put it to [**`OrderedDict()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: How can I display it according to the output specified in the question